# Proving that a complicated complex expotential is periodic or not.

Tags: complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics, trigonometry, signal-processing, periodic-functions

I'm trying to prove that $x[n]=\exp \left(j\left(\frac{\pi}{24} n^2+\frac{\pi}{36} n^3\right)\right), n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is not periodic. I thought of proving that there is no $N \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x[n] = x[n + N]$. I've reached this point:

\begin{align*}
    \exp \left(i\left(\frac{\pi}{24} n^2+\frac{\pi}{36} n^3\right)\right) &= \exp \left(i\left(\frac{\pi}{24} (n + N)^2+\frac{\pi}{36} (n + N)^3\right)\right) \\
    \frac{\pi}{24} n^2+\frac{\pi}{36} n^3 &= \frac{\pi}{24} (n + N)^2+\frac{\pi}{36} (n + N)^3 + 2\pi m \tag{  $e^{ia} = e^{ib} \Leftrightarrow a - b = 2\pi m, m \in \mathbb{Z}$} \\[15pt]
     -2\pi m &=  \frac{\pi\left(2 N^2+6 N^2 n+3 N^2+6 N n^2+6 N n\right)}{72}  \\
     -2\pi m &= \frac{\pi N^2(6 n+5)+\pi N\left(6 n^2+6 n\right)}{72}
\end{align*}

This seems very complicated to me and as it is part of a question of a 2nd-year level assignment, I hardly believe that this is the way to go. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: Moreover, I tried plugging the equation into $\texttt{SymPy}$ and solving as to N, what I got was:

\begin{equation}  N= \pm \frac{3\left(-n(n+1)+\sqrt{-96 m n-80 m+n^4+2 n^3+n^2}\right)}{6 n+5}
\end{equation} Not sure if this helps in any way.

Intuitively I'd expect $N$ not to be a function of $n$, but rather a constant. Maybe I'm wrong in thinking of $m$ also as a constant and not a function of $n$, because that way I could argue that the RHS of N is always a function of $n$ and therefore $x(n)$ is not periodic since $N$ is not fixed.

**EDIT:** Turns out the function **is** periodic. Huge thanks to @Conrad for pointing it out.

Comment: Is $j$ the imaginary unit?

Comment: yes it was, I edited it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Is $n$ a real or an integer? If it's a real then you can use the fact that the derivative of a periodic differentiable function is periodic.

Comment: $n$ is an integer, lemme edit it in. My bad.

Comment: If the sequence was periodic then there would be a $N$ such that $x(N) = x(-N)$. Could try to show that this is not the case (the parts with $N^2$ would be simplifiable)

Comment: @BrunoB So, assuming that $x(n)$ is periodic, then there exists an N such that $x(n - N ) = x(n) = x(n + N)$, for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. If for n = 0, there doesn't exist an N such that $x(-N) = x(N)$ then $x(n)$ can't be periodic, since if it'd be, it'd be for every $n$ is what you're saying?

Comment: Intuitively it feels like if $f$ is a degree $\ge2$ polynomial then $\exp\circ f$ cannot possibly be periodic. I'm not sure how you can prove that in general though

Comment: Something like, $f(k+N)-f(k)$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi i$. If you let $k$ range perhaps a contradiction with polynomial behaviour can be found

Comment: why do you think the expression is not periodic? did you try to do $x(n+12)$?

Comment: @Conrad you are right I believe!! I cannot thank you enough, but I'm really curious as to how you found its fundamental period. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: the period is an integer - I do believe that $12$ works since modulo $2$ we have $(n+12)^2/24=n^2/24+n$ and $(n+12)^3/36=n^3/36+n^2$ and $n+n^2$ is even always; it's easy to check when $x(n)=1$ as that implies $72|n^2(2n+3)$ (and the ratio is even of course) so $n$ is a multiple of $12$ hence any period is a multiple of $12$ etc

Comment: @Conrad, I'm trying very hard to follow you but it seems like some elementary (or not, I wouldn't know) number theory is needed for that. In any case, thank you for your help, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just expand the square and the cube for $n+12$ get rid of denominators and notice that all terms except the original and $n+n^2$ are even (times $\pi$) so when you multiply with $j$ the exp doesn't change by its $2j\pi$ periodicity; but also $n+n^2$ is even so that term times $\pi j$ disappears too so we remain with the original $n$ term

Answer (score 3):

Reduce your formula into its real/imaginary parts with Euler's formula, $e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z$. And recall that complex numbers are equal iff (if and only if) their real and imaginary parts are also equal. For $e^{iz}=e^{iw}$, we must therefore have $\cos z=\cos w$ and $\sin z=\sin w$. (In a geometric sense, if two numbers are equal in the complex plane, they must have the same horizontal/vertical coordinate, which for $e^{iz}$ is its cosine/sine component.)

Hence, if $e^{iz}$ is periodic with some period $k$, such that $e^{i(z+k)}=e^{iz}$, we must also have $\cos(z+k)-\cos z=0$ and $\sin(z+k)-\sin z=0$. We can then use the sum-to-product identities from trigonometry, $\cos A - \cos B=-2\sin\frac{A-B}2\sin\frac{A+B}2$ and $\sin A-\sin B = 2\sin \frac{A-B}{2}\cos\frac{A+B}{2}$. This facilitates finding zeroes since a product is zero iff at least one of its terms is zero. (It would therefore be convenient if the term corresponding to $\sin\frac{A-B}2$ were zero since this would eliminate all cases. And indeed we will see that to be the case.)

Writing your expression as $e^{\pi i f(n)}$, for its real terms we have

$$e^{i\pi f(n+k)}=e^{i\pi f(n)}
\\\cos \left(f(n+k)\pi\right)-\cos \left(f(n)\pi\right)=0
\\-2\sin\left(\frac{f(n+k)-f(n)}{2}\pi\right)\sin\left(\frac{f(n+k)+f(n)}{2}\pi\right)=0
\\\sin\left(\frac{f(n+k)-f(n)}{2}\pi\right)=0\quad\text{or}\quad\sin\left(\frac{f(n+k)+f(n)}{2}\pi\right)=0
$$

But observe also (by the horizontal scaling of a sine wave) that $\sin\frac{a}{b}\pi=0$ iff $\frac ab$ is an integer. So we see that at least one of $\dfrac{f(n+k)-f(n)}{2}$ and $\dfrac{f(n+k)+f(n)}{2}$ is an integer. By a similar argument with the imaginary terms, we would arrive at two fractions for which at least one must be an integer (one being $\dfrac{f(n+k)-f(n)}{2}$ repeated). This has reduced the problem to elementary number theory, as we are now solely concerned with divisibility of integer valued functions.

Substituting your $f$ and simplifying, we see that $\dfrac{f(n+k)-f(n)}{2}=\dfrac{6kn+3k^{2}+6kn^{2}+6k^{2}n+2k^{3}}{144}$. As $k$ is present in all terms of the numerator, setting $k=144$ guarantees the fraction to reduce to an integer. Therefore, this zeroes $\sin \frac{A-B}{2}$ in both the real and imaginary parts, so the original equation for periodicity must be satisfied. Hence, $k=144$ is a period. To find the fundamental period, we need only check casewise through its divisors, and we would find $k=12$.

Answer (score 2):

But $x(n)$ is periodic...

Just note that
$$x(n+144)=\exp\left[i\pi\left(\frac{(144+n)^2}{24}+\frac{(144+n)^3}{36}\right)\right]$$

$$=\exp\left[i\pi\left(\frac{n^2}{24}+12n+864+\frac{n^3}{36}+12n^2+1728n+82944\right)\right]$$

$$=\exp\left[i\pi\left(\frac{n^2}{24}+\frac{n^3}{36}\right)\right]\exp\left[2\pi i\left(6n+432+6n^2+864n+41472\right)\right]$$

$$=\exp\left[i\pi\left(\frac{n^2}{24}+\frac{n^3}{36}\right)\right]=x(n)$$

Comment: would you care to explain why $\exp \left[2 \pi i\left(6 n+432+6 n^2+864 n+41472\right)\right] = 1$? I have no experience with number theory. It'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $6n+432+6n2+864n+41472$ is an integer. $e^{2\pi i k}=1$ for all integers $k$. For more details look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity